# WiFi Printing from Xamarin Android not working

Tags: android, sockets, printing, xamarin.android, wifi

I'm trying the following code for printing via WiFi to HP printer, from Xamarin Android Code:

```
   private async Task Print()
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                //As you will see, all depends on your printer commands
                Socket socket = new Socket("10.10.0.15", 9100);
                PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(socket.OutputStream, false);

                //here is the beginning of printing
                pw.Write(0x1B); //Example of command to start a printer
                pw.Print("THIS IS YOUR AWESOME TEXT FOR PRINT");

                pw.Write(0x0C); //here you release the paper
                pw.Write(0x40); //finish printing
                pw.Flush();
                pw.Close();
                pw.Dispose();
                socket.Close();
                socket.Dispose();

            }
            catch (SocketException ex)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("SocketError: " + ex.Message);
            }
        });
    }
```

But this doesn't work. My Android device and this printer are on same WiFi network. Please suggest what could possibly be wrong here?

Comment: Are you trying to print data from your mobile application on a wifi printer?

Comment: @G.hakim : Yes.

Comment: Does it catch an exception?

Comment: No exception at all. @G.hakim

Comment: If it just runs through and does nothing there could be many reasons one could be your printer is not authorizing the device have you checked the device logcat?

Comment: Device logout shows no error info. Is there a way I can check for callbacks?

Comment: Umm, i'm sorry I don't know.